# Formatting lost while pasting content in PowerPoint using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I have xhtml content saved in SQL database, I want to insert this xhtml content in PowerPoint presentation, so I copy the xhtml content to clipboard, and then try to paste it in Powerpoint. It works fine for normal text with bullets, bold, italics. But with tables when I paste, the formatting is lost and it copies it as normal text.

I put a break point before pasting it through code, and tried to manually paste the content (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), then it works fine, the table gets pasted as it should be.

I am using Office 2010 and VSTO.

The xhtml content comes from InfoPath Form, with RTF field, so it stores data in XHTML form.

When submitting, the data goes to a webservice that inserts data in SQL.

Now, I need to insert this XHTML in PPT.

I use http://www.tcx.be/blog/2005/copy-html-to-clipboard/ to copy html to clipboard.
I have tried both paste and pastespecial with html type, but when pasting tables the formatting is lost.

Comment: I had the same issue when pasting a table as HTML using Paste Special -- the funny thing is -- if I do it manually through the UI (Paste Special, Choose HTML, click OK), all of the formatting comes through perfectly.  But if I do it in code `Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(PpPasteDataType.ppPasteHTML);` (or even the equivalent in VBA), all formatting is lost. -- I think it must be a bug in the object model. :-/

Comment: You can find the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493983/vsto-powerpoint-notes-page-different-colored-words-on-same-line/43210187#43210187

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the file html to the file system and add it as OLE object:

presentation.Slides.addOLE

If I remember well you have to set some option adding the ole to display the content instead of the icon (default behavior).